# Can you hide files and folders on MacOS the same way as Linux?

Tags: osx, filenames, dot-files

I'm trying to make a Python script that creates a hidden folder for a specific file I'm creating across any platform.

I'm aware you can do this easily with Linux by placing "." as the beginning of a file or folder name, but haven't found anything saying that you can do the same with MacOS. I don't have a MacOS system to test with, which leaves me at a roadblock.

Would I be able to just create a directory and/or file named ".file" like in Linux systems, or would I need to use the `chflags` method that I see everywhere I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden filenames is a feature of the Unix shells and of the other standard Unix tools, not of any particular filesystem implementation (a "hidden" name is just a name starting with a dot).

macOS, since it is a Unix operating system, supports hidden filenames just like Linux or any other Unix.

Example on macOS:

```
$ touch file .hidden_file
$ ls
file
$ ls -a
.       ..      .hidden_file    file
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was looking everywhere and couldn't find if that was true.

Comment: @EarthToAccess If it wasn't true, it would be virtually impossible to run basic shell scripts written for Linux on macOS. As it turns out, as long as a script is otherwise portable, scripts works the same on _any_ Unix with regards to these filenames.

Comment: Oh, neat! I genuinely didn't know that. I'll learn to keep this in mind for any other Unix question like this I have in the future.

Comment: Is it true of the finder, and other GUI tools?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor A file or directory with a hidden name will not show up in the Finder or in macOS's file selection dialogs. I'm sure there are exceptions to this (as it's bound to be on non-macOS systems too).